# Invisible Sites and pages

Tags: publishing-page

I am creating a intranet in SharePoint 2010 mainly on publishing sites and pages. If I log in as one user this is the menu I see:

[image: Logged in as user 1]

If I log in as another user I see this menu:

[image: Logged in as user 2]

I can`t find out why the menu is showing for user 1 and hidden for user 2. Somebody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this error was because of the consultant firm who did changes to the masterpage and left the masterpage in draft mode. As soon as the masterpage was approved every change was visible.

For next time: If you do any changes to the masterpage (something you shouldn`t do to the v4.master) remember to approve the change..... And don`t hire firms who clearly isn`t used to work with SharePoint...

Case closed

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This could be for a couple reasons:

First is permissions. The user that has more access gets to view those sites. I would check the permissions on those sites for those two users, make sure they do not have different permission roles.

The second is publishing. There may be times where the pages that you can navigate to may not be published and may be in a draft state which limits who can see the pages, even more permissive users!

Comment: I tried to set the exact same permissions and this did not make a difference. The Sites/pages is not checked out either and they are published. 
I don`t know if this helps or make it worse but I can access the sites/pages through URL but it doesn`t show in the menu! :S