# I have changed the banner but only some users see the change (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

I have changed the banner on our intranet (SharePoint 2010) but only some users see the change. The rest of the users still see the old one. This is now 50-60 days ago.

Any smart ideas?

Comment: What banner are you talking about? Did you give the new one a new filename? Cache issue I'd say from the first glance.

Comment: The banner i am referring to is the background image on s4-title class. 

Could you explain what you mean by cache? in the browser?

Comment: OK, so probably the browsers are caching either the old image, or / and the old css files. Can you try in one of the computers seeing the old image to do a Ctrl +F5 multiple times (to clear cache only for that site)?

Comment: Do you think it might be connected to this error who also is screwed up on the intranet:

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62339/invisible-sites-and-pages?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Might be, but not necessarily

Comment: Are all resources (master page, css, ...) published and visible to Readers ?

Comment: Yes I do think so. Could you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this error was because of the consultant firm who did changes to the masterpage and left the masterpage in draft mode. As soon as the masterpage was approved every change was visible.

For next time: If you do any changes to the masterpage (something you shouldn`t do to the v4.master) remember to approve the change..... And don`t hire firms who clearly isn`t used to work with SharePoint...

Case closed

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in the comments it seems to be a CSS issue. Browsers **LOVES** to cache CSS files.

I don't know how you make alter the CSS on your site, but try adding `revision` in the CSS url.

Example:

```
/Style Library/Intranet/Css/custom.css?rev=08012013
```

In the example above `?rev=08012013` is just todays date (month/day/year). When you update your CSS, update that `rev` parameter with a new date so that browsers will take the updated version instead of the old cached one.

Comment: I confirm that one user is seeing the old CSS file and another user is seeing the new one. This is very strange. I even downloaded a new browser and still nothing...

Comment: How do you include your CSS file in the site? Is it embedded in the masterpage or through Alternating CSS on the user interface?

Comment: The CSS file is in linked from the masterpage:
<link href="/Style%20Library/Intranet/Styles/Intranet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: @Stantonsen Okay perfect. Then do as I write in my answer, so your link looks like this: `<link href="/Style%20Library/Intranet/Styles/Intranet.css?rev=08012013" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: Ok, I have to test this in the weekend. The intranet is in prod...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have checked in the file and published the major version where you did the change